# Is it a good or a bad thing that a suite of quickcheck tests match the implementations?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, business-logic, quickcheck, property-based-testing

I'm trying to get started with Haskell's QuickCheck, and while I am familiar with the concepts behind the testing methodology, this is the first time I am trying to put it to use on a project that goes beyond testing stuff like `reverse . reverse == id` and that kind of thing. I want to know if it is useful to apply it to business logic (I think it very much could be).

So a couple of existing business logic type functions that I would like to test look like the following:

```
shouldDiscountProduct :: User -> Product -> Bool
shouldDiscountProduct user product =
  if M.isNothing (userDiscountCode user)
     then False
     else if (productDiscount product) then True
                                       else False
```

For this function I can write a QuickCheck spec like the following:

```
data ShouldDiscountProductParams
  = ShouldDiscountProductParams User Product

instance Show ShouldDiscountProductParams where
  show (ShouldDiscountProductParams u p) =
    "ShouldDiscountProductParams:\n\n" <>
    "- " <> show u <> "\n\n" <>
    "- " <> show p

instance Arbitrary ShouldDiscountProductParams where
  arbitrary = ShouldDiscountProductParams <$> arbitrary <*> arbitrary

shouldDiscountProduct :: Spec
shouldDiscountProduct = it behavior (property verify)
  where
    behavior =
      "when product elegible for discount\n"
      <> " and user has discount code"

    verify (ShouldDiscountProductParams p t) =
      subject p t `shouldBe` expectation p t

    subject =
      SUT.shouldDiscountProduct

    expectation User{..} Product{..} =
      case (userDiscountCode, productDiscount) of
        (Just _, Just _) -> True
        _ -> False
```

And what I end up with is a function `expectation` that verifies the current implementation of `shouldDiscountProduct`, just more elegantly. So now I have a test, I can refactor my original function. But my natural inclination would be to change it to the implementation in `expectation`:

```
shouldDiscountProduct User{..} Product{..} =
  case (userDiscountCode, productDiscount) of
    (Just _, Just _) -> True
    _ -> False
```

But this is fine right? If I want to change this function again in future I have the same function ready to verify my changes are appropriate and not inadvertently breaking something.

Or is this overkill / double bookkeeping? I suppose I have had ingrained into me from OOP testing that you should try and avoid mirroring the implementation details as much as possible, this literally couldn't be any further than that, it is the implementation!

I then think as I go through my project and add these kinds of tests, I am effectively going to be addding these tests, and then refactoring to the cleaner implementation I implement in the `expectation` assertion. Obviously this isn't going to be the case for more complex functions than these, but in the round I think will be the case.

What are people experiences with using property based testing for business logic-type functions? Are there any good resources out there for this kind of thing? I guess I just want to verify that I am using QC in an appropriate way, and its just my OOP past throwing doubts in my mind about this...

Comment: I daresay business logic is one of the worst applications for property-based checking, because it often blatantly disregards mathematical approachability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to jump in a few months later, but as this question easily pops on Google I think it needs a better answer.

Ivan's answer is about unit tests while you are talking about property tests, so let's disregard it.

Dfeuer tells you when it's acceptable to mirror the implementation, but not what to do for your use case.

It's a common mistake with Property based tests (PBT) to rewrite the implementation code at first. But this is not what PBT are for. They exist to check **properties** of your function. Hey, don't worry, we all do this mistake the first few times we write PBT :D

A type of property you could check here is whether your function response is **consistent** with its input:

```
if SUT.shouldDiscountProduct p t 
then isJust (userDiscountCode p) && isJust (productDiscount t) 
else isNothing (userDiscountCode p) || isNothing (productDiscount t)
```

This one is subtle in your particular use case, but pay attention, we reversed the logic. Your test checks the input, and based on this, asserts on the output. My test checks on the output, and based on this, asserts on the input. In other use cases this could be much less symmetric. Most of the code can also be refactored, I let you this exercise ;)

But you may find other types of properties! E.g. **invariance** properties:

```
SUT.shouldDiscountProduct p{userDiscountCode = Nothing} t == False
SUT.shouldDiscountProduct p{productDiscount = Nothing} t == False
```

See what we did here? We fixed one part of the input (e.g. the user discount code is always empty) and we assert that no matter how everything else varies, the output is invariant (always false). Same goes for product discount.

One last example: you could use an **analogous** property to check your old code and your new code behave exactly the same:

```
shouldDiscountProduct user product =
  if M.isNothing (userDiscountCode user)
     then False
     else if (productDiscount product) then True
                                       else False

shouldDiscountProduct' user product
  | Just _ <- userDiscountCode user
  , Just _ <- productDiscount product
  = True
  | otherwise = False

SUT.shouldDiscountProduct p t = SUT.shouldDiscountProduct' p t
```

Which reads as "No matter the input, the rewritten function must always return the same value as the old function". This is so cool when refactoring!

I hope this helps you grasp the idea behind Property based tests: stop worrying so much about the value returned by your function, and start wondering about some behaviors your function has.

Note, PBT are not an enemy of unit tests, they actually fit well together. You could use 1 or 2 unit tests if it makes you feel safer about actual values, then write Property test(s) to assert your function has some behaviors, no matter the input.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the only times it makes sense for property checking to compare two implementations of the same function are when:

1. Both function are part of the API, and they should each implement a certain function. For example, we generally want `liftEq (==) = (==)`. So we should test that `liftEq` for the type we're defining satisfies this property.
2. One implementation is obviously correct, but inefficient, while another is efficient but not obviously correct. In this case, the test suite should define the obviously correct version and check the efficient version against it.

For typical "business logic", neither of these apply. There might, however, be some special cases where they do. For example, you could have two different functions you call under different circumstances that are supposed to agree under certain conditions.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not a good thing because you're effectively comparing the results of code with results of the same code.

To resolve this chicken-and-egg problem, tests are built on these principles:

- Tests feed predefined inputs and check for predefined outputs. Nothing "random". All sources of randomness are considered additional inputs and mocked or otherwise forced to produce specific values.

  - Sometimes, a compromise is possible: you leave a random source alone and check the output not for exact value but just for "correctness" (e.g. that it has a specific format). But then you're not testing the logic that is responsible for the parts that you don't check (though you may not need to, see below).
- The only way to test a function completely is to exhastively try all possible inputs
- Since this is almost always impossible, only a few "representative" ones are selected

  - And *an assumption about the code is made* that it handles all other possible inputs the same way

    - This is why test coverage metric is important: it will tell you when a code has changed in such a way that this assumption no longer holds

To select the optimal "representative" input, follow the function's interface.

- If there are some ranges in input data that trigger different behavior, edge values are usually the most useful
- Outputs are checked against the interface's promises

  - Sometimes, the interface doesn't promise a specific value for given inputs, variations are considered implementation details. Then you test not for a specific values but only what the interface guarantees.

    - Testing implementation details is only useful if other components rely on them -- then they are not really implementation details but parts of a separate, private interface.

Comment: This answer seems to relate to more traditional unit-test style approach to testing, how does your answer relate to property based testing such as in quickcheck / similar libraries?

Comment: @danbroooks I've never heard of property-based testing before but this is a great opportunity to finally learn some fundamentally new principle. From what I see now, it's some AI logic that does a part of the job picking those "representative" inputs for you -- but the general principles are the same, the checked conditions are static and represent interface rather than implementation.